# Не получается мапить фильтр

Tags: java, веб-программирование, servlet

Здравствуй сообщество проблема такова что когда я в web.xml добавляю мапинг своего фильтра у меня проект начинает лезть туда куда не надо, а без мапинга всё работает корректно. Мне нужно что бы за моим index.html сразу данные ответ/запрос шли в фильтр, а он уже дальше сам посмотрит что куда. Подскажите как правильно сконфигурировать дескриптор развертывания.
Прилагаю иерархию проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так же дескриптор развертывания который не работает по не понятной мне причине:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">
    <display-name>Airport</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>ua.pypek.filters.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Куда не нужно это куда?

Comment: <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>